# "Host key wasn't verified!" when connecting using WinSCP .NET assembly

Tags: public-key, winscp, winscp-net

I'm trying to establish a connection to SFTP server with following code, I'll receive this error message *"Host key wasn't verified!"*.

```csharp
SessionOptions so = new SessionOptions { 
    Protocol = Protocol.Sftp, 
    HostName = "xx.xx.xx.xx", 
    UserName = "usera",
    Password = "user123",
    SshHostKeyFingerprint = "2048 78:1d:67:f9:89:f5:ea:8e:28:84:68:04:f6:50:e7:ea"
};

using (Session s = new Session())
{
    s.Open(so);
}
```

But if I establish a connection using following code, I'm able to connect.

```csharp
System.Diagnostics.Process winscp = new System.Diagnostics.Process();
winscp.StartInfo.FileName = "winscp.com";
winscp.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
winscp.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
winscp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
winscp.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
winscp.Start();

winscp.StandardInput.WriteLine("open sftp://usera:user123@xx.xx.xx.xx");
winscp.StandardInput.Close();
```

I'm so curious to know what I have done wrong in the first method?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your host key fingerprint format is wrong. You are missing a key type (`ssh-rsa` or `ssh-dss`) at least.

See WinSCP FAQ [Where do I get SSH host key fingerprint to authorize the server?](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/faq_hostkey)

---

*Your code that uses scripting succeeds because you have the fingerprint cached. The .NET assembly never uses fingerprint cache.*

*The latest versions of WinSCP [issue a more meaningful message when the fingerprint is not matched](https://winscp.net/tracker/1186).*